# Problem with displaying the ICEPDF toolbar

Tags: javafx, icepdf

I am working on an application where I have to display a pdf in a viewer integrated into the application. To do this I use the ICEPDF library through a SwingNode because I use JavaFX. My problem is that the pdf loads correctly while the panel where the viewer action buttons are located is not visible directly on the viewer display. To display it, I have to hover with the mouse so that all the buttons appear as you can see on the screenshots.

Is there a way to make up for this problem because the end user will surely not know that it is necessary to execute this kind of contour.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this example, https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf/tree/master/examples/javafx ?

Comment: This is the same example that I used in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, I just had to use the factory.buildUtilityToolBar(true) method instead of factory.buildCompleteToolBar(true)